# Small office 802.11n router / access point that doesn't suck

Tags: networking, wifi, 802.1

I'm looking for a wireless n access point for a small office, about 9 people. I've been looking around, and it seems all the n series access points or routers are just terrible. Originally I was looking at a Cisco / Linksys WAP4410N, but the reviews are terrible. They are similarly terrible for almost anything else. I'm willing to pay good money for a solution, but I don't even see one.

I've been looking at some 3com devices, does anyone have any experience with them?

I've toyed with the idea of building my own out of a PC, or using DD-WRT, but the bossman won't allow it. I need something working "out of the box".

Wireless G is out of the question, so is wired networking.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Atwood just did the tought job for you. [Read article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/because-everyone-needs-a-router.html).

I myself was searching for n router, but as at our office we have also G clients, then the pricey [NETGEAR WNDR3700](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/30925-start-your-buying-netgear-wndr3700-reviewed) router was way to go for us, because it is a simultaneous dual band router that performs very well with both N and G clients.

If you only need/have N clients, you may probably go with the other [Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/30889-buffalo-nfiniti-wireless-n-high-power-router-a-access-point-reviewed). At least i couldn't find anywhere that it could do dual band (G and N clients)